# Requisição HttpClient POST com Angular 7 retornando undefined

Tags: angular, http, post, undefined

tudo bem?
Estou com problema para fazer requisições http em meu projeto Angular CLI.

Quando uso `this.http.post(url, dados, config).subscribe(ret => this.retorno = ret)` e em seguida dou `console.log(this.retorno)` ele retorna **undefined**.

Creio que seja algo com relação a "assincronidade", pois se eu coloco um `SetTimeout()` nesse console.log ele mostra o retorno correto do post.

Tenho que fazer algum tratamento nessa requisição? O que eu posso fazer para garantir que a execução só continuará quando essa requisição estiver finalizada?

Passei um dia todo olhando a respeito, em lugar algum vi tratamento especial nessas requisições, algo tão simples que estou perdendo muito tempo, já tô ficando maluco com isso.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Podes fazer da seguinte forma :

```
async minhaFuncao() { 
  this.retorno = await this.http.post(`url`, dados, config).toPromise()
  console.log(this.retorno)
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou assim.

Quer dizer que sempre que eu depender do resultado de uma requisição para fazer algo eu terei que usar async e await.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, quando se faz um subscribe, ele faz a chamada e espera o retorno para executar o código dentro do subscribe, mas libera o programa para executar as linhas seguintes, ou seja ele executa seu console.log(this.retorno) antes de alimentar a variavel this.retorno.

O código abaixo é só um exemplo baseado em sua pergunta, ele vai imprimir no console, primeiro a frase 'bom dia' e depois o seu retorno;

```js
    this.http.post(url, dados, config).subscribe(ret => {
        this.retorno = ret; 
        console.log(this.retorno);
    });
    console.log('bom dia');
```

Comment: Obrigado Edgar, tenho que me acostumar com essas requisições assíncronas.